# NLog: Retaining log files with dates in names for x days

Tags: .net, nlog

I'd like to have a simple log file scheme with NLog: Create the log file with the current date in the name then retain, say, 31 days' worth of log files.

So something like:

```
2020-11-23.log  <-- Today's date
2020-11-22.log
...
2020-10-24.log
2020-10-23.log  <-- Remove this one as being over 31 days old
```

Is this possible?

The impression I get from reading the docs and various blogs is that there may be a problem using the same naming scheme for the live log file and the archived log files.  Also, that I may need to put the archived log files in another folder (although all the blogs mentioning that were over four years old, so I don't know if that's still the case).  However, the docs don't seem very detailed and I'm not sure how up to date the blog posts are that I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in NLog 4.5:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/App.${shortdate}.txt" 
        maxArchiveFiles="31" />
```

And it should just work, unless you start using `archiveFileName=`.

NLog 4.7 introduced the setting `maxArchiveDays=` to help when also using `archiveAboveSize=`.

If you want to use static filename together with `archiveFileName=`, then there are some examples here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples

Comment: Is there any way to test the removal of old log files?  It's fairly simple to use PowerShell to set a file's creation time or last modified time.  I've tried taking copies of the log file and renaming them, and setting creation and last modified times to a month in the past.  But the application doesn't seem to be cleaning them up.  So I'm not sure if my test methodology is wrong or if the removal of old files doesn't work.

Comment: @SimonTewsi You can change to `fileName="${basedir}/logs/App.${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss}.txt"` and have you application log every 1 second. Then `maxArchiveFiles="31"` should kick in after 30 secs. If not then check NLog InternalLogger: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging